# Get hostname and pathname information within Angular Universal

Tags: angular, angular-universal

Does anyone here know how to get access to hostname and pathname information in Angular universal?

Within the client side app you have access to the window object which has that information.

I just need that information on the server?

Answer (score 9):

*With [ngExpressEngine](https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/ng-express-engine):*

**server.ts:**

```
...
app.engine('html',  (_, options, callback) => {
  let engine = ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: ServerAppModule,
    providers: [ { provide: 'host', useFactory: () => options.req.get('host') } ]
  });

  engine(_, options, callback)
})
...
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Inject, Injector, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT, isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';

...

constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document, private injector: Injector, @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {
  if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
    console.log(this.injector.get('host'))
  } else {
    console.log('document: ', document.location.hostname);
  }
}
```

*Without ngExpressEngine:*

**server.ts:**

```
...
app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
  const opts = {
    document: template,
    url: options.req.url,
    extraProviders: [{ provide: 'host', useFactory: () => options.req.get('host') }]
  };
  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, opts)
    .then(html => callback(null, html));
});
...
```

Comment: I'm getting the error `Error: StaticInjectorError[{provide:"host", useFactory:useFactory}]: 'deps' required` with this. My universal version is `5.0.0-beta.6`

Comment: change line to this `{ provide: 'host', useFactory: () => options.req.get('host'), deps: [] }`

Comment: injector.get('host') used as is displayed here is deprectaed.

Comment: How can I get the SSR host Name in routing file ?